# Relative wsdlLocation with multiple wsdl files

Tags: maven, wsdl, wsdl2java, jaxws-maven-plugin

I am using `jaxws-maven-plugin` to generate classes from multiple wsdl files. This is my plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsdltoJava</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <vmArgs>
                    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                </vmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Each generated client code has the following annotation which contains absolute path to wsdl file:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "MyName", targetNamespace = "MyNamespace", wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/some/absolute/path/src/main/resources/wsdl/MyWsdl.wsdl")
```

With `wsdlLocation` property I can make this path relative (wsdl files are included in my target war file). How should I apply `wsdlLocation` property to handle multiple wsdl files?